# How can i get price id associated with a charge in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am capturing 'charge.succeeded' event in webhook. I have one product with 2 prices. One an yearly subscription and another one time purchase. When i get an event in webhook, I want to know what price plan customer chose. I am not seeing any price id reference in charge object.

How can i get the price id associated with a charge object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using Checkout Sessions, in which case you should listen for the `checkout.session.completed` webhook event instead. That event describes a Checkout Session, which contains a list of line items that contain the Price ID: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items-data-price

Comment: I had to do this: 
let checkoutSession = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(session_id, { expand: ['line_items'] });
let price_id = checkoutSession.line_items.data[0].price.id;
Note the "expand" part.

Comment: The problem is that subscription update (an action that occurs for following subscription payments) doesn't emit `checkout.session.completed` event.  
So the question is still - how to get price id from the charge object.